# Lynx-dump cron job not working after installing SSL certificate

Tags: linux, php, ssl, cron, cronjob

I have a cron job that has always worked fine, until we installed an SSL certicate and updated our .htaccess file to redirect all http requests to https. Now, the cron job is not working and I'm receiving the error "exited with error code 1" when trying to process it manually. I am able to run the command (entering the url into my browser and pressing enter) just fine.

We are scheduling tasks in ISPManager (as we always have). The below is the cron job command. Any advice would be greatly appreciated
lynx -dump https://www.example.com/tasks/email_scheduler_process.php

Our .htaccess code is as follows:
`RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`